# argv arguments with pyinstaller windowed apps?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyinstaller, argv

I've got a python script that is currently run on a command line (both macOS and windows) with some command lines.

I'm considering moving to use pyinstaller to bundle everything up to make life easier for the users. One interesting feature of pyinstaller is that it has the `--windowed` option that gives it an icon, and is runnable from the gui.

My question is: if I use this, how do I get data into the argv? Where command line arguments would normally go?

If I create a "config file" and have the users drag and drop that into the app, would the filename become argv[1]?